# How to order rows by highest average of another table with same id

Tags: sql, average

I have table A and B

**A**

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
| 1  | abc  |
+----+------+
| 2  | xxx  |
+----+------+
| 3  | qwe  |
+----+------+
```

**B**

```
+------+--------+
| a_id | rating |
+------+--------+
| 2    | 1.5    |
+------+--------+
| 2    | 5      |
+------+--------+
| 3    | 2.5    |
+------+--------+
| 1    | 3      |
+------+--------+
| 3    | 1      |
+------+--------+
```

Now I want to get all data from **A** ordered by the average of rating in **B**.

The result should be:

```
xxx // because the average in table B is 3.25

abc // because the average in table B is 3

qwe // because the average in table B is 1.75
```

I am sure I have to use stuff like `AVG()` and `ORDER BY DESC` and a subquery, but I don't know how to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work if you are using SQL server, as you wanted all the data from A, I added left join instead of inner join.

```
select a.ID, a.data , avg(b.rating) Avgrating from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.ID = b.a_id 
group by a.ID ,a.data 
order by Avgrating desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `avg()` aggregation function :

```
select A.data as "Data", avg(rating) as "Rating"
  from A
  join B on B.a_id = A.id
 group by A.data;

Data    Rating
----    ----
qwe     1.75
xxx     3.25
abc     3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ac55b4c2ffd19271a178d8c562bf3944)</kbd>